# java udp broadcast problem

Tags: java, networking, udp

I have problem with udp broadcast behaviour,

```
public static final int PORT = 34567;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("server")) {
        int port;
        if (args.length >= 2) {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        } else {
            port = PORT;
        }

        DatagramSocket sr = new DatagramSocket(port, InetAddress.getLocalHost());

        while (true) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            DatagramPacket pct = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            sr.receive(pct);
            String s = new String(buf);
            System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\0", "") + " " + pct.getAddress().toString());
        }
    } else {
        DatagramSocket ss = new DatagramSocket();
        ss.setBroadcast(true);
        byte[] b = new byte[100];
        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length);
        p.setAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { (byte) 255,
                (byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255 }));
        p.setPort(PORT);

        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            String s = new Integer(i++).toString();
            System.out.println(s);
            b = s.getBytes();
            p.setData(b);
            ss.send(p);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
```

on machine A when I run both server and client it receives several packets at once, so I have following output

```
0 /192.168.253.5
0 /192.168.253.5
1 /192.168.253.5
1 /192.168.253.5
2 /192.168.253.5
2 /192.168.253.5
```

on other machine B when I do the same, server doesn't receive any packet at all

when I run client on machine A and server on machine B, server receives packets

when I run server on machine A and client on machine B, server doesn't receive any packets

I suppose that it depends on local address of sending udp socket, as every machine is connected to several networks, and local address is chosen randomly (is it true?), and it only sends broadcast to the network which local address belongs to, am I right?

if so, how can I send broadcast to all networks pc is connected?
also why several same packets is received (the first case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DatagramSocket sr = new
>   DatagramSocket(port,
>   InetAddress.getLocalHost());

Change that 2nd argument to null, or omit it. You don't care which IP address you receive datagrams from.

> p.setAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(new
>   byte[] { (byte) 255,
>                   (byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255 }));

Broadcast to 255.255.255.255 has been deprecated for about 20 years. Use a subnet-specific broadcast address. Better still, investigate *multicast.*

Answer (score 1):

UDP requests are often restricted to the current subnet (unless you gateway passes then onwards which is unusual). So this is one issue.

The machine not getting any UDP requests could also have a local firewall that is blocking it too.

Comment: no firewalls, but machine A is connected to several networks(192.168.0.123/24, 192.168.159.17/24, etc.) and machine B is connected to several networks, but they are directly visible so no router are involved

Comment: I think you need to use Multicast Socket's and use groups... have a look @ http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/multicast.aspx